# How to change font style and text color in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have two queries : 
1) I want to change color and font in Android studio editor window.  
2) Can I export that settings for my other laptop

Below image you see all method have orange color & all variable have light-blue color. I want to achieve that please help me

[image]

Comment: first question has been already answered. Answer to second question is here: Yes, the settings can be exported for other laptop.
**Android Studio -> File -> Export Settings -> Ok** and just select what you want to export. In other laptop: **File -> Import Settings** and select the previously exported `settings.zip` and good to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change Font colors

**--> SDK Manager -> Editor -> Color Schema**

[image]

Change Font Style

**--> SDK Manager -> Editor -> Font**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Settings allow users to change the functionality and behavior of an application.

You should visit  **File-> Settings->Editor>Color Scheme->General**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want your own custom color then  you can set it by **Color Schema** from Setting, And if you want to set some other default you can pick a plugin, I suggest you can try this installing **Rainglow Color Schemes** plugin

1. Change by your choice customizing colors
   **Settings -> Editor -> Color Schema -> Custmize color from right Panel**
2. First Install **Rainglow Color Schemes** from the marketplace **( Settings -> Plugins -> MarketPlace Tab -> Search and install 'Rainglow Color Schemes' and restart IDE)**
   then after open color schema **Settings -> Editor -> Color Schema ->** and select any rainbow Schema from **Schema** dropdown list

[image]